# Dataweave: How to filter and concatenate values for certain keys in json array

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

My input is

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "FirstName": "LISA",
            "Sku1": 10074895,
            "Sku2": 10074896,
            "Sku3": 10074897
        },
        {
            "FirstName": "JOSE",
            "Sku1": 10128582,
            "Sku2": null,
            "Sku3": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Output I want is a string concatenating all the SKUs

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "FirstName": "LISA",
            "Skus": "10074895, 10074896, 10074897"
        },
        {
            "FirstName": "JOSE",
            "Skus": "10128582"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm new to Dataweave and not sure how to do this
Thanks in advance

### EDIT 1

My input will have more keys than "FirstName", that I will want to exclude

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "FirstName": "LISA",
            "Country": "CA",
            "Sku1": 10074895,
            "Sku2": 10074896,
            "Sku3": 10074897
        },
        {
            "FirstName": "JOSE",
            "Country": "CA",
            "Sku1": 10128582,
            "Sku2": null,
            "Sku3": null
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the solution I have come up with, can someone help fix this solution . The problem is that there is a trailing "," at the end of "Skus" in the output

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

fun mapToResponseModel(customObj) = do {
    var skus = createSkus(customObj)
    var withoutSkus = mapWithoutSkus(customObj)
    ---
  withoutSkus ++ { "Skus": skus }
}
    
fun createSkus(customObj) =
    keysOf(customObj) reduce (key, acc = "") ->
        if ((key contains "Sku") and (customObj[key] != null))
            customObj[key] ++ "," ++  acc
        else
            acc

fun mapWithoutSkus(customObj) =
    customObj mapObject (value, key) ->
        if (value != null and !(key contains "Sku"))
            { (key): value }
        else
            {}
---
{
    value: payload.value map (customObj) ->
        mapToResponseModel(customObj)
}
```

Output

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "FirstName": "LISA",
      "Country": "CA",
      "Skus": "10074897,10074896,10074895,"
    },
    {
      "FirstName": "JOSE",
      "Country": "CA",
      "Skus": "10128582,"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Edit 1 try with the following script:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var skuValues = payload.value map {
    ($ filterObject (($$) contains "Sku" ) mapObject  {
           a : $
    })
}
---

value: payload.value map {
     "FirstName": $.FirstName,
     "Country" : $.Country,
     "Skus":  skuValues [($$)] filterObject($ != null) pluck $ joinBy ","
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this approach:

In the resultant object as far Skus is concerned we take the iterating object and remove `FirstName` from it which leaves us with the Sku1, Sku2, Sku3.  [Filter](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-core-functions-filterobject) on the same to avoid null and then use [pluck](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-core-functions-pluck) to get the values in an array after which you could use [joinBy](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-core-functions-joinby) to form the string.

**Script**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
value: payload.value map {
     "FirstName": $.FirstName,
     "Skus": (($ - "FirstName") filterObject($ != null) pluck $ joinBy ",")
}
```

**Output**

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "FirstName": "LISA",
      "Skus": "10074895,10074896,10074897"
    },
    {
      "FirstName": "JOSE",
      "Skus": "10128582"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution Salim, however I will have more keys besides "FirstName" that I will want to exclude. So is there a way instead to include just the keys that start with "Sku" ?

Comment: Can you look at my Edit 1 in the question please

Comment: That should be a new question instead of an in place edit in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if i should be doing this though you can modify your function to check if the sku* key being used is the last key (to not add "," at the end).

```
fun createSkus(customObj) =
    keysOf(customObj) reduce (key, acc = "") ->
        if ((key contains "Sku") and (customObj[key] != null) and (keysOf(customObj)[-1] != key ))
            acc ++  customObj[key] ++ "," 
        else if ((key contains "Sku") and (customObj[key] != null) and (keysOf(customObj)[-1] == key ))
             acc ++  customObj[key]
        else
            acc
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats a lot of functions written, is that just to modularize? Below can be tried with no external functions:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
value : (payload.value map ($ mapObject ((value, key, index) ->

((key) :  value ) if !(key contains "Sku")

 )
 ++

 "Skus" : joinBy(valuesOf($ filterObject ((skuVal, skuKey, indexOfSku) -> (skuKey contains "Sku") and !isBlank(skuVal))),",")
 
 
 ))
```

With your functions, a bit of modifications are needed like below to work without extra commas at the end:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

fun mapToResponseModel(customObj) = do {
    var skus = joinBy(createSkus(customObj),",")
    var withoutSkus = mapWithoutSkus(customObj)
    ---
  withoutSkus ++ { "Skus": skus }
}
    
fun createSkus(customObj) =
    keysOf(customObj) reduce (key, acc = []) ->
        if ((key contains "Sku") and (customObj[key] != null))
            acc << customObj[key]
        else
            acc

fun mapWithoutSkus(customObj) =
    customObj mapObject (value, key) ->
        if (value != null and !(key contains "Sku"))
            { (key): value }
        else
            {}
---
{
    value: payload.value map (customObj) ->
        mapToResponseModel(customObj)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var input1 = {
    "value": [
        {
            "FirstName": "LISA",
            "Sku1": 10074895,
            "Sku2": 10074896,
            "Sku3": 10074897
        },
        {
            "FirstName": "JOSE",
            "Sku1": 10128582,
            "Sku2": "",
            "Sku3": null,
            "Sku4": null
        }
    ]
}
var keyFilter = 'Sku'
fun joinStr1(obj, keyFilter, delimiter) = obj filterObject ( (($$) contains keyFilter) and $ != null and $ !='') pluck $ joinBy delimiter
fun joinStr(obj, keyFilter, delimiter) = obj filterObject ( (($$) contains keyFilter) and !isBlank($)) pluck $ joinBy delimiter
---
value: input1.value map {
     "FirstName":    $.FirstName,
     "Skus":        joinStr($, keyFilter, ',')
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).